# Cordova/Crosswalk <video> element only plays once, then black

Tags: android, cordova, video

I have an issue with the latest [`cca`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cca), if I add a `<video>` to the page and play it it pretty much always works the first time. If I then try to play the video again the view appears to come to the surface but the video never actually plays.

I've found various bug reports and PRs but the issue still prevails.

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/pull/1827/commits/67ad7129c37ff98b049469e673bfa46f3dfdb856
https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7215

I've tried cache busting the video, destroying and recreating the element, stopping and rewinding and then playing the video but nothing seems to work.

The video(s) are all mp4 with an aac audio track, f-frames are disabled and I've tried webm videos as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, there was a couple of issues with the particular setup and the video files.

The Cordova app is running on Android, on an ODroid C2.

For some reason the MP4 container doesn't work on this particular setup, WebM works 100% of the time.
Some of the videos were VP9 encoded which didn't work in either MP4 or WebM container.

The fix is to use VP8 encoding in the WebM container.